# What is the current state of distributed storage?

Tags: web3js, dapp-development, dapps, ipfs, swarm

Swarm, IPFS, Filecoin, etc..

What project(s) is typically best practice for dapp storage and what is the current state and future roadmap for dapp storage? Any recommendations on the best dapp stack?